# Ansible on Ubuntu

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-16.04, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have created two Ubuntu machines on virtual box. ***I am able to ping the other machine from the terminal of the other.***
However when I ping from ansible I get the following error.[image]

My /etc/ansible/hosts file is :

[image]

Can I get the solution for this ?

Comment: Make sure you have python2 and ssh installed on both target machines, and the firewall is allowing port 22 as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you read [the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ping_module.html) you will notice:

> This is NOT ICMP ping

So the way in which the `ping` command works and the way in which Ansible module works is different.

Reading further, Ansible `ping` module is described as:

> Try to connect to host, verify a usable Python and return pong on success.

So Ansible tries to connect (and the default connection method is SSH) and execute Python code.

In your case Ansible failed to connect.

SSH connectivity is a prerequisite, so you need to configure that before you'll be able to use Ansible. For Ubuntu 16.04 you might need to additionally install OpenSSH.

Refer to the [official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html) for the installation and configuration steps.

---

On top of that, Ubuntu Server 16.04 does not install Python 2 by default, so you need to manually add it (Ansible support for Python 3 is still experimental).

Refer to [answers under this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/101591/457662) on AskUbuntu.

Then you still might need to set a parameter in the inventory file to tell Ansible to use Python 2. Or make Python 2 the default interpreter.

Comment: Actually 16.04 comes with python2 as the default interpreter for the system.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Is it really? I must have been misguided by their Vagrant box. Or maybe it changed some time on the way, but my provisioning scripts remained intact...

Comment: Their vagrant box would not have any python installed because the Vagrant image is going to be minimal. I am actually running a 16.10 right now on my laptop and `python --version` yields `Python 2.7.12+`.

Comment: No, `ubuntu/xenial64` (v20170417.0.0) does have Python 3 installed, but not Python 2 and my understanding was that it is how Ubuntu Server 16.04 is distributed. Desktop indeed has Python 2 as default, but I don't have a fresh Server to check now.

Comment: Ok so sounds like 3 for server and 2 for desktop. Weird.

Comment: I downloaded Server 16.04.02 LTS and with default settings (no manual package selection) it does not install neither Python 2 nor 3.